# html onload field focus problem

Tags: html

I use the following html code to focus a input field when page loaded, why it does not work?

```
<input class="myinput" id="the_username" onLoad="$('#the_username').focus()" size="30" type="text" />
```

I would like to do it in html like above by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `onLoad` XHTML attribute [can be bound only](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xhtml/quickref/xhtml_event_onload.html) to the `<body>` and `<frameset>` tags.

So put it on your `<body>` tag, or preferably (because Javascript inline in HTML is horrid) set the `onLoad` handler in proper Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $('#the_username').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your HTML

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#the_username').focus();
})
```

I'm not sure whether input fires an onLoad

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ‘HTML5’ `autofocus` attribute:

```
<input class="myinput" id="the_username" type="text" autofocus>
```

This will work in the Firefox 4 and the latest stable Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

For browsers who don’t support `autofocus`, it’s easy to write a fallback, especially since you’re using jQuery in this case.

```
$(function() {
  if (!('autofocus' in document.createElement('input'))) {
    $('#the_username').focus();
  }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why the original approach failed.